# Use same session object in multithread request without session lock

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, session

In an asp.net web application (mvc 3,.net 4.0) we are developing, we have some troubles with object on session when we use it in async operation. (It uses Async Targeting Pack library).
ASP.NET processes sequentially when we create many async requests to this object. This is because of asp.net session provider is getting locked at the begining of http request.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178587.aspx
When EnableSessionState attribute of MVC Controller is set as  ReadOnly, we can get concurrent response. This workaround does not work for us because we need to store some data in the session as threads complete.

The only thing we require here is a thread-safe, multitasking enabled asp.net session state provider.

For a solution;

1) Should we implement "SessionStateStoreProviderBase" abstract class in our project and implement our own custom state manager? What can be the best practice(s)  ?

2) Is there any 3rd party library to achieve this solution or any .net built-in library?